# In Jenkins how can i run a job only after completing all builds in the pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have a pipeline running and some other jobs. For example:

- I have "Job A" & "Job B"
- "Job A" triggers pipeline & pipeline starts buildA, buildB, buildC.
- Once the pipeline completes all the builds then it should trigger "Job B"

I have went through lockable resource plugin, but usage is not so clear. can anyone suggest what can i do ?

Comment: guys can anyone suggest me here??

Comment: Can you add more detail? What have you tried and why didn't it work?

As you have currently described your problem I think you just need to add a downstream build step to Job A. Alternatively you could use https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin to trigger the pipeline and Job B as different phases.

Comment: @KeyanP i have tried to check on lockable resource plugin but it was not clear for me.
As of now what i did is i kept a condition under "Build Triggers" - "Build after other projects are built" but this doesn't  work for my requirement.
Now with this setup when buildA in pipeline completes Job B gets triggered, but my requirement was that all the builds under pipeline should complete then Job B should start

Comment: @KeyanP i tried adding  block downstream build step to Job A
- just for info "Job A" is just passing parameters to pipeline

This is not working as Job A would pass all the time so once the Job A is success automatically Job B is triggered

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `build job` function. For example, you have 2 stages and each of them build a job : `build job: 'JobA', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param1', value: param1]]` inside the JobA, you build ur buildA, buildB, buildC. Once JobA is finished, do the same function for your JobB.

Comment: i am currently using "build job" in the pipeline job . But it's not always 3 builds that run in pipeline there might be as many builds as it can run.

Comment: you can put `if()` verification ?

Comment: Stage JobA : `if(buildA == 'true'){build job: ...} if(buildB == 'true'){build job: ...}'` and so on.

Comment: sorry this was not my requirement. let me clearly explain:

Job-A passes few parameters to pipeline Job.
Pipeline Job has few jobs (job-a, job-b).
For example, if Job-A passes parameters (1a & 2b). Pipeline job would run (job-a, job-b) each parameter in sequence.
Once the sequence is completed then Job-B should trigger